# Find entries for "You replied to" in Outlook 2011 via Applescript

Tags: outlook, applescript

Having selected a particular message in outlook 2011, I can see from the GUI
"You forwarded this message..." with a link to the message.

Programatically, I can do something like:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set myMessages to current messages
  repeat with theMessage in myMessages
    log "Subject: " & subject of theMessage & " Replied:" & replied to of theMessage
  end repeat
end tell
```

So I can pull out the message(s) that are selected without issue, and see that they were replied to.

I do not see in the dictionary how I find the reply, however. Outlook can do it since it shows it in the GUI, but programatically the best I can think of is to pull out the "in reply to" as text from the header, then iterate through the entire sent items space doing text comparisons to the headers in those messages.

That will not scale for more than a handful of messages.

Any suggestions on where to look next. The Dictionary for Outlook does not disclose any key values or a search framework I can see.

Comment: I gave up trying to find an answer and assume that outlook is just not ideal for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what what I can tell you will need to parse out the the header of each meassage for the message id  then search each of the sent message header for its "in-replay-to:" and see if that line has a matching id. So far thats the only way I can see to do it kind of a pain but there may be ab better way not sure